# VSTO Outlook Add-in will not move item another store

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook Add-in that moves an email item to another folder in another mailbox. At least, it used to do that. Now it no longer moves it. I wrote another test Add-in that moves an email item to another folder in the current user's mailbox and it does work, so I my question is, is there something about moving items to another mailbox that is causing a problem?

Here is some code to explain things:

To perform the move to another mailbox, the code creates stores for each mailbox using this line,

```
stores = Globals.ThisAddIn.OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").Stores;
```

then iterates through each store using a foreach loop,

```
foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
```

It gets the current inbox, for use later,

```
destinationMailboxFolderInbox = (Outlook.Folder)store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

If this store DisplayName matches the one I specified as the destination, it proceeds to search the subfolders for the one I want,

```
if (store.DisplayName.Equals(destinationMailbox))
{
    foreach (Outlook.Folder myFolder in destinationMailboxFolderInbox.Folders)
    {
        if (myFolder.Name.Equals(destinationMailboxFolder))
        {
            item.Move(myFolder);
```

The problem is, it does not appear to run that last foreach loop (looping through the folders).

Like I said, it works when I change it to use my current user's mailbox.  It does not work when I set it to the shared mailbox that the current user can access.

Is there some other step I am missing?

Comment: Update: I found another post that mentions something that may be related:
`It's often not a good idea to modify the contents of a (sub)set of items while looping over them. You could modify your code so that it first identifies all of the items that need to be processed, and adds them to a Collection. Then process all the items in that collection.

Basically you shouldn't be removing items from the Inbox while you're looping through its contents. First collect all the items you want to process (in your Inbox loop), then when you're done looping, process that collection of items. `

Comment: Does it fail for all items? Or just some?

Comment: When you say "does not appear to run that last foreach loop", that means the previous statement (store.DisplayName.Equals(destinationMailbox)) returns false, which means store's display name is different from what you expect.

Comment: If fails for all items. During testing, I added some output statements in between the first foreach loop and the second foreach loop. It displays the output statements only for the first one.

Comment: I will double-check tomorrow and confirm what I saw during testing.

Comment: I  was also working on using item.Copy instead of item.Move.  Resolving some object errors.

Comment: I double-checked and confirmed the behavior that I saw. I tested the same code, only difference is whether it checks my own user's inbox subfolder, or the other shared mailbox inbox subfolder (same name of subfolder). In my own mailbox, the code works. When I switch it to run the code in other mailbox, it does not execute that 'foreach' loop, which is "foreach (Outlook.Folder myFolder in destinationMailboxFolderInbox.Folders)." Next comment will explain more.

Comment: When the code goes into the other mailbox (as a "store"), it gets the default Inbox using this line, "destinationMailboxFolderInbox = (Outlook.Folder)store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);"

Later, it uses 'foreach' to look through all the folder/subfolders - "foreach (Outlook.Folder myFolder in destinationMailboxFolderInbox.Folders)"

It must not find any folders/subfolders, because nothing in that loop executes.  What is preventing it from finding the folders under that Inbox?  What can I use to check?

Comment: I found this related topic -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382371/vsto-outlook-cannot-find-subfolders-of-shared-inbox
"VSTO Outlook: Cannot find subfolders of shared inbox"
The person who posted said he solved it by fixing something related to permissions. Not sure where to fix permissions, but I will look into that.

Comment: Did you open that mailbox in Outlook as a delegate store? Can you see the Inbox and its subfolders?

Comment: Someone made a settings change somewhere that allowed me to see the mailbox in Outlook. I can see the Inbox and subfolders. As far as I can tell, I have full permissions.

Comment: So destinationMailboxFolderInbox.Folders.Count always returns 0?

Comment: Correct, the Count always returns 0.

Comment: We are going to try logging in as the user who owns the folder. If it works for that user, it indicates a permissions issue.

Comment: I had some success in my test Add-In by changing the GetDefaultFolder line to use the method that belongs to the Namespace class rather than the Store class. I will post the details later as an "answer." However now I am getting some SignTool errors in my old Visual Studio environment. Researching.

Comment: Well, after the changes, it found the item (in the correct folder) and moved it, but moved it into the user's folder, not the shared inbox folder. May have to make other adjustments.

Comment: I made some adjustments. I changed it to use GetSharedDefaultFolder instead. It resolved the recipient and put me into the Inbox. But the inbox.Folders.Count still always returns zero. So I am back to a permissions issue that I do not know how to resolve. When I ask the Admin, he says I already have full permissions.

Comment: I found this other post where the user posts a similar permissions problem, and he answers his own post by saying he solved the issue due to permissions, but he does not say how. When I attempt to post an answer asking for more details, the forum moderators delete my post. Dmitry can you post a comment on that forum post to ask the user to provide details? I cannot post a comment. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382371/vsto-outlook-cannot-find-subfolders-of-shared-inbox)

Comment: Outlook stores delegate default folders in the primary mailbox's OST file. It does not sync the subfolders. Do you see the same behavior if you disable the cached mode?

Comment: I do not have permissions to disable cached mode. I will ask my admins to do that, and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: The Admins did not give permission to change the cached mode setting.  
My alternate plan is to get this email moved using Rules.  Or last resort, the user will simply have to move it manually.  The primary purpose of this Add-In is to save the attachments.  The moving it afterward is secondary.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Is using Redemption an option?

Comment: Pardon the late reply on this. I do not recall getting a notification about your message.

I do not know of this "Redemption" option.

I ended up developing a workaround.  The workaround was to create an Outlook "Quick Step" button to move the email.  So the user will click my VSTO-coded Add-In button to save the attachments and then click the Quick Step button to move the email to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was either a permissions issue or a bug. Instead of resolving directly, I ended up developing a workaround.

The workaround was to create an Outlook "Quick Step" button to move the email. The Outlook user will click my VSTO-coded Add-In button to save the attachments and then click the Quick Step button to move the email to the folder.